# how to print numbers from list between run time entered two numbers in python

Tags: python

how to print numbers from list between run time entered two numbers in python.

eg:

```
lst = [23, 5, 7, 8, 90, 67, 90, 0]

first = int(input('Enter Your Number:'))

second = int(input('Enter Your Number:'))


first = 7

second = 67
```

the answer is [8, 23]

```
lst = [23, 5, 7, 8, 90, 67, 90, 0]
first = int(input('Enter Your Number:'))
second = int(input('Enter Your Number:'))

for i in range(0, len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == first:
        for x in range(0, len(lst)):
            if lst[x] == second:
                if x > i:
                    ans = lst[lst[i]:lst[x]]
                    print(ans)
                else:
                    ans2 = lst[lst[x]:lst[i]]
                    print(ans2)
```

Comment: Start with iterating over list elements, not its index. Then check if `first > i > second`.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? It isn't clear what you're trying to do, nor what the current result is. See: [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is just a filter:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: first < x < second, lst)))
```

or

```
print([x for x in lst if first < x < second])
```

If you want the output sorted, you can use `sorted` on either the original list or the filtered list:

```
[x for x in sorted(lst) if first < x < second]
sorted(x for x in lst if first < x < second)
list(filter(lambda x: first < x < second, sorted(lst)))
sorted(filter(lambda x: first < x < second, sorted(lst)))
```

Since the actual filtering operation is O(n), while sorting is O(n lg n), I recommend sorting the potentially shorter result rather than the original list.